# Tomar solo valores decimales en laravel

Tags: laravel

Necesito ayuda para tomar solo la parte decimal de un número, por ejemplo si tengo 3,45 necesito que me de solo el valor después de la coma  que es 45.

Se que con number_format(numero) me da solo el valor entero hay alguna forma que solo me de el decimal?

Comment: Por favor añade tu código, por ejemplo ese valor que deseas formatear viene de una consulta a la base de datos?

Comment: Anja viene de una base de datos  mi código es este @foreach($productos as $product)           <h1>{{productos -> name}} </h1>     <p> Precio: {{number_format($product->precio_actual)}}</p>  @endforeach.                          Como tal quiero tomar el precio entero para ponerlo en grande  y el decimal para ponerlo más chiquito pero necesito separarlo primero, no se si hay otra forma de hacer eso

Comment: Que tipo de dato es ese número `3,45`?  no parece un float, ya que el separador es una coma.

Comment: Es de tipo decimal

Comment: Lo que te pregunto es que tipo de dato en PHP, porque el separador de decimales para números no es la coma, sino el punto. Lo que muestras parece un string. Puede ser? También sería bueno saber si siempre va a estar presente la parte decimal, o como aparece cuando el precio es un número entero. Para el precio $5, ves 5 o 5,00?

Comment: Si es un decimal, sorry es 5.00 como tal quiero separar la parte entera de la decimal para poder poner por ejemplo el 5 en grande y el .00 un poco más chico no se si me explique bien

Comment: Si fuese un número, un float por ejemplo, no te va a mostrar la parte decimal `(float) 5.00` va a mostrar `5`, no `5.00`. La única forma que se me ocurre para que puedas mostrar `5.00` es que el tipo de dato sea un string. La respuesta para cualquiera de los casos relativamente sencilla, pero sería distinta, incluso puede haber varias maneras de hacerlo. Puedo asumir que es un string por lo que comentas del `5.00`, solo espero a que tú lo digas con convicción **Es string** o **Es float**, **Es double**.

Comment: Puedes usar [gettype](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.gettype.php) para ver el tipo de dato `{{gettype($product->precio)}}`

Comment: Dice que es de tipo string

Comment: Muchas gracias me diste una idea, como es una dato de tipo string use la función substr(string,strlen(substring)-2,strlen(string)) y perfecto me lo particiona.

Comment: Ok, genial que encontraste una solución. Puedes agregar una respuesta de cómo funciona. En adición agregué también una respuesta con otra opción, y si esperas un poco, posiblemente aparezcan más opciones de otros usuarios

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basándome en los comentarios, de que el tipo de dato es `string`, que el separador es un punto `.`, y que siempre van a estar presente las dos partes, la entera y la decimal, una opción puede ser usando [explode()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.explode.php), que devuelve un array de strings, que para tu caso solo tendrá dos elementos, el elemento con índice `0` con la parte "entera", y elemento con índice `1` con la parte "decimal", que puedes usar para mostrarlos en distintas etiquetas Html. Por ejemplo:

```
@foreach($productos as $product)
    <p>{{$product->name}} </p>
    @php($precio = explode(".", $product->precio_actual))
    <p>Precio: {{ $precio[0] }}<small>.{{ $precio[1] }}</small></p>
@endforeach
```

Comment: También me funcionó, gracias

Answer (score 1):

Aquí, les dejo otra solución strlen(parametro) me da el tamaño del arreglo y substr(par1,par2,par3) lo que hace es crear un substring donde par1 es el string a particionar y par2 y par3 el inicio y el fin. Gracias a todos por la ayuda

```
@foreach($productos as $product)
<p>{{$product->name}} </p>
<p>Precio: {{FLOOR(format_number($product->precio_actual,2)}}.{{substr($product->precio_actual,strlen($product->precio_actual)-2,strlen($product->precio_actual))}}</p>@endforeach
```

Answer (score 1):

Lo puedes hacer de una forma simple siempre y cuando el valor sera positivo.

`$fractional = $float - floor($float);`

Esto sin embargo te va a dar la parte decimal como decimal, si tenemos

`$float = 3.45;` el resultado de $fractional sera `0.45', si necesitas optener solo el 45 puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera.

```
$sign = localeconv()['decimal_point'];

$fractional = explode("$sign", $float);

$value = end($fractional);
```

o así en su versión de una linea.

`$fractional =  explode(localeconv()['decimal_point'], $float)[1];`

Comment: probé con `$float = '3.45';` `$fractional = $float - floor($float);` y me da como resultado `0.45`. Pero la pregunta dice "si tengo 3,45 necesito que me de solo el valor después de la coma que es 45". ¿Como haría para obtener solo la parte después del separador decimal?

Comment: En ese caso vas a tener que hacer un explode del valor, para no poner el signo quemado puedes hacer lo siguiente `$sign = localeconv()['decimal_point'];` de esa manera te quedara `$fractional = end(explode($sign, $float));`

Comment: puse eso así `$float = '3.45'; $sign = localeconv()['decimal_point']; $fractional = end(explode($sign, $float));` y me dá este error `ErrorException Only variables should be passed by reference`. ¿Podrías modificar la respuesta con algo que hayas probado que funcione y responda la pregunta?

Comment: Ahí te agrego el ejemplo funcionando a la respuesta,

Comment: Ahí funcionó, gracias

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con este codigo en el SQL.

```
Modelo::where(..algo..)->select('*',' SUBSTRING(precio - FLOOR(precio),3) as parte_decimal')->get();
```

Primero resto los decimales al numero, usando la función  `FLOOR` para redondear al menor numero sin decimales, luego dado que el resultado sera `0,##`  obtengo solo los valores desde la opción 3 (después de la coma) hasta la final con la función `SUBSTRING`

o si esta usando PHP debes hacer lo siguiente.

```php
<?php $numero = number_format(4444.5,2) // por defecto el formato es #,###.## ?>
<?php $entero = "$numero".split('.')[0] ?>
<?php $decimal = "$numero".split('.')[1] ?>
 <strong>{{ $entero }}</strong><small>{{ $decimal }}</small>
```

Comment: No me funciona me da el error cannot instantiate abstracto class

Comment: esto no va, ninguna de las dos opciones funciona.